# Do all non-hero melee attacks do 50% damage?

Tags: star-wars-battlefront-2015

Most of the soldier melee attacks seem to cause about 50% damage to another regular soldier.  But other times, I am not so certain, because sometimes soldiers seem go to go down after single hit.  On the other hand, perhaps they were wounded.

Can attacking the head or certain locations cause more melee damage?

Do all non-hero melee attacks do 50% damage to other regular soldiers?

Comment: Pretty sure that back attacks are a one hit. I remember it happening that way in the beta at least.

Comment: @Dupree3 I used to think the same thing as well until I just tested it! I can confirm it is a one-hit KO if you hit them in the head. All other body shots are 50 damage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's 50 per hit unless you hit them in the head.

This happens to me a lot as I am one of those guys that loves to put on the personal shield and go for the uplink. I just tested this to be sure - I had wondered why it always seemed to be a one-hit KO when the recipient was crouched

Comment: I verified this recently I was facing a stormtrooper with full health and died instantly.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that you can head shot with a melee attack, and that makes it a one hit kill. (This is speculation)

However, I have been killed by single melee attacks, unless I was somehow lagging and never saw/heard the first hit. I have also had people one shot me from behind with a melee hit again, lagging would be the only other explanation.

In summation, I have seen one hit melee kills, so it has to either be lag causing me to not see the first hit or blaster shots, or something is causing a melee hit to be instant kill, and headshots are the only thing I can think off.

Edit: As a side note, it MAY also be back attacks as Dupree3 mentions, but if so, it must be a DIRECT back attack. I have hit many people from what i thought was behind, and had it not be a single hit kill. I had to bash them again

Comment: [Zephkiel](https://forums.battlefront.starwars.ea.com/profile/Zephkiel) on the [battlefront forum said](http://starwars.ea.com/starwars/battlefront/forums/discussion/comment/88635#Comment_88635): "Small blasters do 50%, and large blasters do 100%". Have you noticed any of that?

Comment: Meaning the dmg depends on what gun type you are wielding? I havent noticed that, but havent paid much attention to it. I normally use the targeting blaster, but I can try to pay attention tonight and see if I can identify a difference.

Comment: I haven't noticed that exactly either, I always use the burst fire rifle and it seems to take two hits.  I've posted this question everywhere and there are a lot of different responses.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's 50 per hit, regardless of where you hit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what determines it for sure, but I have definitely gotten several one hit melee kills on enemies who were at full health while playing. The melee for battlefront is a bit blocky, and hard to use, causing either a hit or even sometimes a miss. But I am positive that it is possible, easy even, to get one hit melee kills. The most simple explanation for this is the head, but I think it also may be the back.